# What does char word[100] mean in C

Tags: c, string, char

What does `char word[100];` mean in C. I'm assuming it means that it sets the limit of characters to 100. I'm still not sure though.

Comment: It means that `word` variable can hold up to 101 characters.

Comment: no. Just 99 @YashKaranke

Comment: With this declaration the compiler allocates an array of exactly 100 bytes and You may do whatever You want with every one of them using `word[x]`.

Comment: We expect you to perform your own research before posing a question here.  The answer to this question can be found in every C textbook and in most introductory C tutorials.

Comment: @snr wouldn't it be logical that it hold 101 characters because 100 being the number of characters and it starts from 0 and goes up to 100, therefore from 0 to 100 comes to the total of 101.  let me show an example `word[0]` `word[1]` `word[2]` `word[3]` ......`word[100]` ,... will come to total of 101

Comment: @YashKaranke It doesn't include 100, it's length 100, i.e. 0 to 99.

Comment: @YashKaranke, try re-reading what you just wrote.  If 100 is the number of characters in the array -- which it is -- then the number of characters in the array is 100.  The number of characters determines which index values are valid, not the other way around.

Comment: Ok ok ...Agreed with snr, Dukeling and John ... Guess need to go to basics again.

Answer (score 3):

`char word[100]` creates an array of `char`s, similar to how `int word[100]` creates an array of `int`s.
This character array will allow you to store 100 characters from index 0 to 99.

Comment: @Michi, Disambiguated the wording.

Comment: @ikegami Agree, but it should be corrected. Oh I see, you did it yourself. Does SO let you to do that ?

Answer (score 2):

`word[100]` is a string (array of char data type). But string in C is a bit 
 different from ordinary array. A string will have a null character ('\0') at the end. So `word[100]` can contain 99 characters from your input which will be indexed from 0 
- 98 and a null character will be placed in index number 99.

Comment: It could be used to store a NUL-terminated string, but that's far from a necessity.

Comment: An array of `char` is *not a string* - `word` *may* contain a string, or it may contain multiple strings, or it may contain a sequence of character values that do *not* make up a string, etc.

Comment: @Manny_Mar, you're wrong. Read what I've written about indexing again.

Comment: @John Bode Would you please read this one and comment? :https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_strings.htm

Comment: @Najat: The wording is a bit misleading.  Per the [C Language Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), 7.1.1/1: "A *string* is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character."  All strings are *stored* in arrays of `char` (or `wchar_t` for wide strings), but not all arrays of `char` contain a string.

Comment: @Manny_Mar: If `word` is 100 elements wide, then the valid range of indices is 0-99 - index 100 is past the end of the array.  You can store a 99-character string in indices 0-*98*, with the 0 terminator in index 99.

Answer (score 2):

This declaration creates `word` as a 100-element array of `char`:

```
      +---+
word: |   | word[0]
      +---+
      |   | word[1]
      +---+
      |   | word[2]
      +---+
       ...  
      +---+
      |   | word[99]
      +---+
```

Each `word[i]` stores a single `char` value.  In C, arrays are indexed starting at 0, so for an N-element array, the range of valid indices is 0 to N-1.  You can store a string *up to* 99 characters long in `word` (elements 0 to 98), leaving 1 element free for the string terminator.  Naturally, you can store shorter strings as well:

```
  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7       99
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+   +---+
|'H'|'e'|'l'|'l'|'o'| 0 | ? | ? |...| ? |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+   +---+
```

You can also store multiple strings in a single array:

```
  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11      99
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+   +---+
|'H'|'e'|'l'|'l'|'o'| 0 |'W'|'o'|'r'|'l'|'d'| 0 |...| ? | 
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+   +---+
```

Or, you can store 100 characters that do *not* make up a string<sup>1</sup>.

C declaration syntax is somewhat complex - the type of an object is determined by a combination of *declaration specifiers* (type specifier, type qualifiers, alignment specifiers, etc.) and a *declarator*.

In the declaration

```
char word[100];
```

`char` is the type specifier, and `word[100]` is the declarator.  The "array-ness" of `word` is specified as part of the declarator - if we change the type specifier:

```
int word[100];
```

we now have a 100-element array of `int`.

Array-ness, pointer-ness, and function-ness are all specified in the declarator:

```
T a[N]; // a is an N-element array of T
T *p;   // p is a pointer to T
T f();  // f is a function returning T
```

where `T` stands for some combination of type specifiers and qualifiers.  Array-ness, pointer-ness, and function-ness can be combined into arbitrarily complex types:

```
T *a[N];      // a is an N-element array of pointers to T
T (*a)[N];    // a is a pointer to an N-element array of T
T *(*f())[N]; // f is a function returning a pointer to an N-element array of
              // pointers to T
```

etc.

---

1. Either because you aren't storing a 0-valued character, or because you're storing multiple 0-valued characters that don't mark the end of anything.